# How to have posts have a parent in permalink like site.com/blog/postname

Tags: posts, slug

I have a site that I'm working on and I want to have a custom blog page. Unfortunately if I use Settings>Reading to set the blog page it clears out my custom blog page.

Since I can't set the blog page I'm not quite sure how to set the permalink hierarchy to include the slug for the blog page like site.com/**blog**/postname

Not sure if I explained it clearly but I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: So you want to use a custom blog page as the home page of the blog, but when you do it loses the custom template?

Comment: Correct and it loses the /blog/ part of the slug on posts

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding a plugin that allows me to customize the permalinks to solve my problem.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/